# How to get final iteration number in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In Meteor we have the '@index' operator to get the index value of the iteration. But I wanted to get the total number of iterations then print that number on the page. So the page at top might read the total number of boys in a group.

For example, I might have something like:

```
Total = {{#each StudentMale}} {{formatMaleCount @index}} {{/each}}
```

and a register helper just to add 1 to the number

```
Template.registerHelper('formatMaleCount', function (count) {
return count + 1;
});
```

and this would print:

```
Total = 1234567
```

I'd like to have:

```
Total = 7
```

Coming up short on how to do this. I tried to have the helper put the values in an array, but this wouldn't work since a new array is produced on each iteration.

Comment: well you are inside an each, so even if you manage the way to get the last index, it will print 7 N times depending on how much objects do you have on the each iterator, so why dont you simple make the helper formatMaleCount to return a Make.find({foo:'bar'}).count() ?

Comment: @Ethaan You're right. Just use the length of the array that it's iterating over, rather than using the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StudentMale is presumably an array or cursor, so in a new helper:

If it's an array:

```
arrayLength( array ) {
  return array.length;
}
```

Or if it's a collection:

```
studentMaleLength() {
  return StudentMales.find().fetch().length;
}
```

Then just call your helper.